# Gradle build error

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I try to build a fatJar using gradle unfortunately it does not work. Gives me this error

```
Cannot create directory 'C:\Users\User\build\tmp\expandedArchives\maven-toolchain-1.0.jar_6m0pv69i8jujen0j76d9kruaz\META-INF' as it already exists, but is not a directory
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip'.
```

What is this error all about?

I have following code:

```
jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by just using this kind of "pattern".

```
jar {

archiveName = "myjar.jar"

manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'myjar.jar',
               'Implementation-Version': version
}
// adds runtime dependencies to jar package
from(configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
    // remove all signature files
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
}
```

}